# rsync replace existing directory with a symlink

Tags: rsync, symlink

on server1: /dir1 is a symlink to dir2

on server2: /dir1 is a directory with its own content

I want to use rsync to make server2:/dir1 be a symlink to dir2, just as it is on server1.

If I do this on server1:

```
rsync -azvs --delete /dir1 user@server2:/dir1
```

then I actually get a new (broken) symlink on server2:

```
/dir1/dir1 -> dir2
```

(so it's copying the symlink into the existing /dir1 directory instead of replacing it)

Can I instead get rsync to trample the existing /dir1 directory with the symlink?

**Edit**: I thought the above command would work because of this comment in the man for rsync under the `--copy-dirlinks` section:

> Without this option, if the sending side has replaced a directory with
>   a symlink to a directory, the receiving side will delete anything that
>   is in the way of the new symlink, including a directory hierarchy (as
>   long as --force or --delete is in effect).

However, the behavior appears the same with and without `--force`, and with and without `-k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are specifying `/dir1` as the destination. You need to go up one level.

```
rsync -azvs --delete /dir1 user@server2:/
```

Comment: Be sure not to append a final `/` to your source path, or you will be very sad.

Comment: Crap. I don't even need to test this to know I'm an idiot. Thanks.  And your warning made me chuckle... I'd be sad indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would use Rsync to make a symlink in the same server. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but if you want to make a symlink **inside server2** with source in **/dir2** and link in **/dir1**, you should simply run: `ln -s /dir2 /dir1`.

Just in case, as stated in the other answer and extending the issue with your line.

Deconstructing your command:

```
rsync -azvs --delete /dir1 user@server2:/dir1
```

You are doing an rsync, archive mode (recursive, owner, group, include symlinks as symlinks, among others) , compressing, verbose and no space-splitting:

```
    -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
    -z, --compress              compress file data during the transfer
    -v, --verbose               increase verbosity
    -s, --protect-args          no space-splitting; wildcard chars only
```

Also, you are deleting your destination differences:

```
        --delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
```

Then you are using as origin `/dir1`, which means the whole directory, not just the contents (because there is no trailing slash **"/"**).

And the destination is `user@server2:/dir1`, considering **/dir1** was a symlink and you were using the `-a` flag for archive, you are copying the symlink inside the root **/dir1**, ending with this:

```
server2:/dir1/dir1
```

Comment: Sorry the explanation was a bit confusing.  See the accepted answer to see what a dummy I was.